# Playing audio using nodejs REST API?

Tags: node.js, rest, audio

I have a nodejs REST API that uses oauth authentication. A client can use a third party application to record sound files (.wav format) that are stored on a NAS server. This server is mounted on the REST API server.

On the frontend web application (PHP), I want to allow users to listen to their own .wav files using some kind of audio player. It is important that they can only access their own files (there's a mongoose model that links files to clients).

The .wav files are generally very small (max 250kb).

I wonder what the best approach is for allowing users to play their audio? I've been searching for best practices for transferring binary data over a REST API, but there doesn't seem to be a straight answer. I've looked at streaming but I'm not sure how to implement the oauth authentication. Any pointers in the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is enable authentication for your application.  This could be done many ways but I highly suggest using http://passportjs.org/.  It integrates with basically every authentication provider out there.  You would then need to have a user log in and then associate their login to the .wav files they have access to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but that's not really the problem, I already have authentication in the frontend application (PHP) which puts the oauth token in the session, which is needed for authentication with the API calls.

Comment: You could use the oauth token to do ACL's based on that.